# Getting a '404 Not Found' error, when testing serialised JSON-B output

Tags: bash, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jms, jsonb

I'm trying to build a simple JSON-B program, which converts a java object to a JSON string. The programme also uses the @JsonbProperty annotation on the pojo, to map an unmatched json property to the java object.

The string is then sent to a JMS queue, for a JMS consumer to pick up. I'm using a bash test script, to print the serialised json output in the console. The test script and .json files have been provided, and i'm just assuming they're correct.

When I run the bash script I'm getting a '404 Not Found' error, with no output in the console. I've attached the java code, the .json file, the test scripts and the error messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Bash Script

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @order.json http://localhost:8080/hsports-catalog-jax/hsports/api/order
```

Bash Script Terminal Error

```
[21:27] ~/IdeaProjects/JEE8_Essential_Training/HSports_CatalogProject/jaxrs_module/src/resources Marc's Mac >> ./test.sh
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>[21:27] ~/IdeaProjects/JEE8_Essential_Training/HSports_CatalogProject/jaxrs_module/src/resources Marc's Mac >>
```

JAX-RS Endpoint

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/order")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class OrderEndpoint {

    // injects JMS producer from ejb module
    @Inject
    private JmsService jmsService;

    // method for placing an order
    // accepts Order object JAX-RS resource
    // method will convert it to json
    @POST
    public void placeOrder(Order order) {

        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();    // json builder object
        String json = jsonb.toJson(order);      // converts order object to json representation
        System.out.println(json);

        jmsService.send(json);
    }
}
```

JMS Producer

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JmsService {

    // injects JMS queue we want to send the message to
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/HsportsQueue")  // JNDI name
    private Queue hsportsQueue;

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext context;

    // code that sends the message to the consumer
    public void send(String message) {

        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = context.createTextMessage(message);   // message object
            context.createProducer().send(hsportsQueue, textMessage);       // producer object
            System.out.println("Message sent to JMS queue");                // console println

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JMS Consumer

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = {
                @ActivationConfigProperty(
                        propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/jms/queue/HsportsQueue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(
                        propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
        },
        mappedName = "/jms/queue/HsportsQueue")

public class JmsConsumerBean implements javax.jms.MessageListener {

    public JmsConsumerBean() {
    }

    // defines what the consumer does, when msg is received from jms queue
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Message received, JMS Consumer message-driven bean");
        try {
            System.out.println(message.getBody(String.class));
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Java Pojo

```
public class Order {

    private Long orderId;
    private String storeName;
    private Customer customer;  // new class created
    private List<InventoryItem> items;

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }

    public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    // maps json-inventoryItems to java-item
    @JsonbProperty("inventoryItems")
    public void setItems(List<InventoryItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

JSON File Content

```
{
    "orderId": 1,
    "storeName": "Franklin Park",
    "customer": {
        "customerId": 1,
        "firstName": "Kevin",
        "lastName": "Bowersox"
    },
    "inventoryItems": [
        {
            "inventoryItemId": 1,
            "catalogItemId": 1,
            "name": "Sneakers",
            "quantity": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Problem solved. I had the wrong module name in the URI...idiot!